# No coverage information will be saved because all LCOV files cannot be found in my javascript project using Github actions

Tags: sonarqube, github-actions, sonarcloud

I am using [sonar github action][1] for my code coverage, but it is coming as zero in my Github actions.

This is my workflow:

```
  sonarcloud:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          # Disabling shallow clone is recommended for improving relevancy of reporting.
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: SonarCloud Scan
        uses: sonarsource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

and my sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey={key}
sonar.projectName={name}
sonar.organization={org}

sonar.sources=src/
sonar.tests=test/
# sonar.test.exclusions= < No exclusions currently >
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

Please help me solve the issue.
[1]: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action

Answer (score 0):

check the exact location of *lcov.info* file

> sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=**coverage/lcov.info**

for my scenario locv.info file located in `coverage/<project_name>/locv.info`

> sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=**coverage/<project_name>/lcov.info**